# Share cookies between android webview control and browser

Tags: android, browser, webview

How to share cookies between android webview control and browser.

I see that I can put cookies to webview, but I dont know how to get them from browser.

I tried few methods, but I never got exactly the same cookies as browser has.

For example:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("http://m.website.com");
```

Comment: were you able to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think what you are trying is possible. My understanding is that the cookie stored for webview will be stored in the application's sandbox and browser (is another application) will not have access to your application sandbox.

BTW, why do you want these cookies to be shared?

EDIT: CookieManager might do the trick, check this link out

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

Comment: I want use website widget which data is dependent on cookie. Its ecommerce application, on mobile pages, m.website.com, is cookie containing id of last visited poroducts. Now I'm creating new adroid application where I also want tu put list of last visited products throught browser.

Comment: Updated my answer and added a possible solution.